# How to use iPhone Simulator on VS 2015 without running the XAMARIN Mac Agent?

Tags: iphone, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios

How to use iPhone Simulator on VS 2015 without running the XAMARIN Mac Agent ?

I don't have a MAC Machine. When i run the Project, XAMARIN Mac Agent window pops up

" You must  be connected to  the build server before running the  application. "

How should i skip this Pop-up ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run the iPhone Simulator in Visual Studio without a connect mac. It is a requirement. iOS Applications need a connected mac to be able to debug/deploy.

Comment: thank you .. i decided to rent the mac .. from macincloud. thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark as answer if it answered your question.